# Custom (interactive) shell with Python

Tags: python, shell

I'm currently trying to make some small shell-like utility for a custom script I wrote, so I can easily work with it (it's rather simple, so an interactive shell would be perfect).

Do you have any resources for me on how to create a shell in Python 3? I spent googling for a while, but all I could find was information about IDLE and similar *Python* interpreters. But I would rather want to know how to write a completely custom and command line based shell.

My approach would be hooking the stdin/out for commands, but given that the Python library offers so many great utilities, I want to make sure there if there is no better way.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [cmd](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/cmd.html) module in the standard library could be a start -- if you have any trouble using it, please post more specific questions (ideally with some toy example showing what you're trying to achieve and what you're getting instead!).

Comment: another python library ishell also serves this purpose.  https://github.com/italorossi/ishell

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at [pyparsing](https://pypi.org/project/pyparsing/). It is definitely only about lexing and parsing, but that's definitely the hardest part of the problem.

Comment: The link is down. Look here: https://pypi.org/project/pyparsing/